# strange opencv.pc (pkg-config) file

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I built opencv on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.  I can link to opencv libraries if I issue the following command:

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv --cflags` my_code.cpp  -o my_code `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

However if I issue the following command:

```
gcc -g -O2 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-multichar  -o main main.o -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcxcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcvaux
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To trouble shoot the problem I issued:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

and got:

/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so

I guess that explains the problem but I don't understand why opencv.pc doesn't include the short hand "-llib" format for library locations like a usual .pc file.  Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the location of the library headers that pkg-config provides you with

```
pkg-config opencv --cflags
```

For me, the output is

> -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include

If you add that, it should work fine